# Fill in the Blank- Unique Strings

Tags: java

I have already filled out most of the blanks; however, I am stuck on these final three, everything I have tried has given me errors.

```java
public static String unique(String s) {
    _____ = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        Integer count = counts.get(c);
        if(count == null) {
            _____
        }
        counts.put(c, count + 1);
    }
    String result = "";
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(_____) {
            result = result + c;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public void test_Unique() {
    assertEquals("km", unique("ffifkmi"));
    assertEquals("es", unique("test"));
    assertEquals("confuse", unique("confuse"));
}
```

Comment: In `unique`, a variable `counts` is used.  Where could it be defined?  Once you have solved that, check out what [`count.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) will return.  What needs to be done if it returns `null` but we want to increment the value it returned by 1?  Finally, under what conditions would you append a character to the result string?  Insert that into the last gap and you're done!

Comment: @Peter This looks damn much like homework. You do know that this is not a site that should solve your homework for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the algorithm works.

It iterates over the characters of the string and counts the number of occurrences of each character in it. To associate a count to a character you need a Map **(1)** which is in your sample pretty obvious since it already shows its construction, so you actually only need a variable for the map. Now how should this variable be named? You have this piece of code

```
counts.get(c);
```

which shows a how the count for a particular character is requested from what? A [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Then you have:

```
if  (count  ==  null)
```

If you look at the specification of the [Map#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) method you will see when this call returns `null`

> **Returns:**
>
> the value to which the specified key is mapped, or **null** if this map contains no mapping for the key

This is the case when you first encounter a charter for which there is no mapping yet in the map. So you need to put a count for that character on the map. Next piece of code tells you with witch value it should be initialized:

```
counts.put(c, count + 1);
```

The count is first incremented than put on the map, so for the first occurrence to be `1` you need to have `count` initialized with `0` **(2)**

Then you start iterating again over the chars of the string to determine which is unique. What does this mean? exactly, the `count` must be equal to `1` **(3)**

Answer (score 0):

1) Map counts
2) count = 0
3) counts.get(c) <= 1

Comment: I don't think your answers are correct but I do think Peter should do his own homework.

Comment: Did a minor fix for 3). Some people need a bit of help to get through :)